# Series of Singular/Plural noun

Tags: word-usage

Which is correct -

Responding to a Series of ***questions*** , official said....

Responding to a Series of ***question***, official said...

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct.

"A series" implies there are multiple questions, making it plural. (Hence the addition of the 's').